# NO INDEX KEY COULD BE USED on Joomla

Tags: joomla

I'm using joomla 3.5. After the installation I turned on Debug mode, but there are many "NO INDEX KEY COULD BE USED" messages shown. This is effect to other functionality such as can't remove category, user or other module.

Error Image.
[NO INDEX KEY COULD BE USED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4cFq.png)
(Environment:MySQL 5.5.28 , Php 5.3.28, Apache 2.2.23)

Answer (score 0):

For every table in your database there can be indexes (this is optional) that will improve the performance of certain SELECT queries on that table. The warning that you see when you turn on debug mode in Joomla is that the query mentioned would benefit from an index.

Normally the Joomla or 3rd party developers should do this. The debug mode is used by the developers to find these kind of problems.

To be clear, nothing is going wrong when you see this message. It's only an indication for developers that improvements can be made.

Comment: Hi Peter, you've been a member of [joomla.se] Stack Exchange for 4 years, but you haven't yet posted a question or answer there.  If possible, please help to grow that community by sharing your insights there.

Comment: To "_help to grow that community by sharing your insights there._" https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58842/joomla